# Playback MP4 video clip in Chrome

Tags: gmail, chrome-for-android, mp4

I get several emails everyday from my security camera system. Such mail contains links to video clips (aprox 20 sec each) form cameras in MP4 format. I use native Gmail client for Android.
After clicking on such link the clip is open in browser but nothing is playback. Only controls are display and shows clip time "zero". I try both native and  Chrome as a browser
The same clip is properly playback when I use Chrome on desktop (Linux) platform.
For test purposes I downloaded MP4 clip from RedTube ;-) which is properly playback on my Android device. But when I try to playback it in the same way as clips from security camera, the result is the same (only controls are displayed in browser). 
What I have to do to reach proper playback MP4 files in my Android unit?

I use Galaxy S4 mini, Android ver 4.4.2

Comment: Does the link point to the MP4 file itself, or to a web page that has the video embedded?

Comment: Point to mp4 file itself

Comment: I think the problem has been fixed in the latest release.